# How do I reformat all Word Form date fields from m/d/yyyy to yyyy-mm-dd using VBA?

Tags: mysql, vba, ms-word

I am working on a custom VBA script that dynamically collects user-entered form data and inserts it into a MySQL database. My problem is, to convert form field data into an SQL script, I have to use string functions; thus, all my data, including dates, gets inserted as text. I need to convert all the dates the form collects from m/d/yyyy format to yyyy-mm-dd format for my MySQL database to infer schema and load date data into DB without an error. I need to do so dynamically, meaning, the script has to work regardless of how many date fields are collected. I have:

```
Private Sub Submit_Button()

Dim doc as Document
Dim control As ContentControl
Dim FormDateField As Date
Dim ReportNumber As String
Dim myValues As String
Dim myFields As String
Dim conn As ADODB.Connection
Dim strSQL As String

Set doc = Application.ActiveDocument
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.open "DSN=ABCD"

For Each control In doc.ContentControls
  Skip = False
  If Left(control.Range.Text, 5) = "Click" Or Left(control.Range.Text, 6) = "Choose" Then
    Skip = True
  Else:
    myFields = myFields & control.Tag
    myValues = myValues & "'" & control.Range.Text & "'"
  End If

  If Not Skip Then
    myFields = myFields & ", "
    myValues = myValues & ", "
  End If

  Next

myFields = Left(myFields, Len(myFields) - 2)
myValues = Left(myValues, Len(myValues) - 2)

strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 ("
strSQL = strSQL & myFields
strSQL = strSQL & ") VALUES (" & myValues
strSQL = strSQL & ")"

conn.Execute strSQL
MsgBox "Form data saved to database!"
conn.Close

End Sub
```

However, my program is crashing because it is trying to insert a string into the date field (the actual final form will have many date fields.) I thought if I change the date format to MySQL format, it may be able to infer schema? I tried adding

```
If IsDate(control.Range.Text) Then
  control.Range.Text = Format(control.Range.Text, "yyyy-mm-dd")
Else FoundOne = False
End If
```

and I know in Excel you can do:

```
Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
Application.ReplaceFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd"
```

Any suggestions? Thank you.

Comment: Just to be sure, in your description you have "the form collects from d/m/yyyy format", but in your review of the methods available in Excel, you have Application.FindFormat.NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy". So which format(s) might your code actually have to deal with? m/d/yyyy? d/m/yyyy? Either?

Comment: @slightlysnarky, it does not actually matter what format the date is currently in. What matters is that I need all dates collected from form fields to be in yyyy-mm-dd format in hopes that MySQL would be able to infer schema and read dates as dates.

Comment: So if you have a content control containg "3/2/2020" you don't mind whether you store that as 2 March 2020 or 3 Feb 2020? That's what I was asking about. Or maybe your content control is a *date* content control? You didn't say.

Comment: Good catch @slightlysnarky. Thank you. I meant m/d/yyyy. Edited. But nevertheless. Regardless of original date format likely to be m/d/yyyy I need it to be in yyyy-mm-dd.

Comment: Please be clear about what you are collecting data from - you mention both form fields and content controls. They are not the same thing. If it's content controls - as appears most likely from your code - what types of content controls are you trying to harvest dates from? If they're date-picker content controls (which is what you should use to avoid input errors), retrieving the date value and reformatting it is trivial.

Comment: @macropod, I have reduced the code for simplicity. I am collecting data from a variety of fields. Date fields, you are correct, are harvested from a date picker. Nobody wants t deal with February 30th type of situation! Thank you in advance for any input you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all dates are in date-picker content controls, you could use:

```
Private Sub Submit_Button()
Dim CCtrl As ContentControl, bSv As Boolean, DtFmt As String
Dim myFields As String, myValues As String, strSQL As String
With ActiveDocument
  bSv = .Saved
  For Each CCtrl In .ContentControls
    With CCtrl
      If .ShowingPlaceholderText = False Then
        Select Case .Type
          Case wdContentControlDate
            DtFmt = .DateDisplayFormat
            .DateDisplayFormat = "YYYY-MM-DD"
            myFields = myFields & .Tag & ", "
            myValues = myValues & "'" & .Range.Text & "', "
            .DateDisplayFormat = DtFmt
          Case wdContentControlRichText, wdContentControlText, wdContentControlDropdownList, wdContentControlComboBox
            myFields = myFields & .Tag & ", "
            myValues = myValues & "'" & .Range.Text & "', "
          Case Else
        End Select
      End If
    End With
  Next
  .Saved = bSv
End With
If myFields <> "" Then
  myFields = Left(myFields, Len(myFields) - 2)
  myValues = Left(myValues, Len(myValues) - 2)
  strSQL = "INSERT INTO TABLE_1 (" & myFields & ") VALUES (" & myValues & ")"
  Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
  With Conn
    .Open "DSN=ABCD": .Execute strSQL: .Close
  End With
  Set Conn = Nothing
  MsgBox "Form data saved to database", vbInformation
Else
  MsgBox "No form data found", vbExclamation
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. I will incorporate this on Monday and test it!

Answer (score 1):

As you noticed, Word does not have Application.FindFormat or Application.ReplaceFormat, but if you know the format is m/d/y you should be able to do this:

```
myValues = myValues & "'" & ymd(control.Range.Text) & "'"


Function ymd(s as String) As String
Dim v As Variant
v = VBA.split(s, "/")
ymd = Right("0000" & v(2),4) & "-" & Right("00" & v(0),2) & "-" & Right("00" & v(1),2)
End Function
```

Everything else (e.g. the way you add commas to the list of dates) looks fine but I have not tested.

Comment: Thank you @slightlysnarky. However, I am looking for a solution that would dynamically identify all fields that are of date type and adjust their format. Something like: if field type is change format to "yyyy-mm-dd" if you know what I mean.

Comment: @Annabanana looks like macropod’s closer to the mark on this one anyway - if he’s answered your question please mark it as the answer. Otherwise more clarification of what is needed please!